# Reading property of JSON response with nodejs 'request'

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

So I ran into this problem. I have a mocha test suite, to test the API endpoints. The API is sending a JSON response on the path, which looks like this:

```
{
  "error": false,
  "message": "post deleted"
}
```

In the test suite I am sending a DELETE request:

```
it('deletes post by given ID', function(done){
    request.delete({url: baseUrl + '/posts/delete/' + test_config.valid_post_id},
      function(error, response, body){
      expect(body.error).to.be.false;
      console.log(body.error);
    done();
  });
 });
```

This test fails, and body.error is printed to console as undefined. However when I do

```
console.log(body);
```

I get the JSON object. 
My question is - how should I go about parsing the body response?

Thank you.

Comment: body = JSON.parse(body) and then you can use the properties of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `body` will be a serialized JSON string, and you'll have to parse it to access its attributes

Try this

```
var parsedBody = JSON.parse(body)
console.log(parsedBody.error)  // => should give false
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using below

var jsonobj=JSON.parse(body);
console.log(jsonobj.scales.scale_id);

still am getting **undefined** in my console .

Comment: Can you print out the whole JSON and make sure the .scales.scale_id property exists on the object?